# Is there any other possibilities to solve this issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables like reservation,booking,billing in my db. I am using join query.

I have more than five common fields in these 3 table. while executing the query the common fields are overwriting.

Is there any way to get every values from the 3 table without overwriting and also without giving alias name for these common fields?

*[Update: according to a recent comment, the OP is asking how to fetch such columns using CodeIgniter]*

Comment: AFAIK not possible without an alias. But given that they are the same fields presumably they contain the same data? And what's wrong with an alias?

Comment: can u give me the solution for this pblm..?

Comment: @Richard Having columns with the same name is not a problem, just run `SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS a, 3 AS a` in your favourite query browser.

Comment: i am having the common fields such as fname, lname etc., likewise i am having 6 to seven fields. if i want to give the alias, i have to give for every thing. to avoid this pblm only i said i dont want alias.

Comment: @Alvaro - isn't that using an alias though? Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of alias?

Comment: @Richard I wasn't answering the original question, I just said that duplicate columns are not an issue on their own. It's bad practice but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE reservation (
    ->  id INT,
    ->  data VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE booking (
    ->  id INT,
    ->  data VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE billing (
    ->  id INT,
    ->  data VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO reservation (id, data) VALUES (1, 'Lorem ipsum'), (2, 'Dolor sit amet');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO booking (id, data) VALUES (1, 'Consectetur adipisicing'), (2, 'Consectetur adipisicing');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO billing (id, data) VALUES (1, 'Tempor incididunt'), (2, 'Ut labore');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM reservation
    -> LEFT JOIN booking ON reservation.id=booking.id
    -> LEFT JOIN billing ON booking.id=billing.id;
+------+----------------+------+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
| id   | data           | id   | data                    | id   | data              |
+------+----------------+------+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
|    1 | Lorem ipsum    |    1 | Consectetur adipisicing |    1 | Tempor incididunt |
|    2 | Dolor sit amet |    2 | Consectetur adipisicing |    2 | Ut labore         |
+------+----------------+------+-------------------------+------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Update

The OP is now asking how to do it in the CodeIgniter PHP framework, which I've never used. All I can provide is a general PHP advice. Most DB libraries provide methods to fetch query results as both numeric arrays and associative arrays. If there are duplicate column names, you have to avoid the second one and stick to numeric arrays. E.g., instead of this:

```
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
}
```

... you have to do this:

```
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
}
```

Comment: it is possible in mysql directly. but., i am executing this query in php codeigniter package. the key values are overwriting. is it possible to solve this pblm now.?

Comment: @Sakthi When you made the question, how could you think that mentioning CodeIgniter or even PHP was not relevant...? :-P - See my update answer.

Comment: This answer is the right one. Your column names are "overwriting", and if you try to access them by their NAME in PHP, you won't get what you want. However, if you try to access them by their INDEX - you can have ovewriting names and still obtain the data.

Comment: i know your solution in correct and i didnt say your answer is wrong brother. i asked the solution for my pblm. Now., how can i access by their index in codeigniter.? it is possible in core php. i dont know how to do it in codeigniter package. can u guide me to do it..? and thanks for your solutions..

Comment: @Sakthi - May I suggest that you edit your question and paste the part of the code you are using to read the values?

Comment: u told me to use code   while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){} know... that one how should i use in codeigniter format..?

Comment: @Sakthi - Your question suggests that you've already written some code. Isn't that the case?

Comment: here the pblm is, i am executing the query in codeigniter. if it is core php., i can change the second parameter in mysql_fetch_array() to get the same field names. but., i dont know how to do that in codeigniter.

Comment: @Sakthi - I'm giving up. It's impossible to help you with your code if you consider it some sort of industrial secret that cannot be revealed.

Comment: nothing secret in this brother.                                     $query = "select reservation.*,booking.*,billing.*,hotels.name from hotels,reservation left join booking on reservation.id=booking.resid left join billing on booking.resid=billing.resid where reservation.hid=hotels.id and reservation.id=$resid";

$res = $this->db->query($query);
var_dump($res->result_array());

Answer (score 0):

Create views for each of your tables, giving new unique names to each of your repeated named fields.

Ok, so this is still theorectically using an alias method, but you need only do it once, and then use the new field names from the views. And your existing queries will still work on the existing field names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you will need to use aliases in this situation.

But do you really need to select the same column three times? Can't you just select the data from one column. And then when you want to update, you do three updates?

*Edit: I read "common fields" like the same data is replicated in multiple tables, perhaps you only ment that the column names are the same?*

Comment: here values are different. but., field names are same.

Comment: in that case i think (again, not 100% sure) that aliases is your only solution. is there a particular reason why you can't use them?

Comment: i already told that i am having the field 6 to 7 fields like that. i have to give alias name for everything. thats y only i said i dont vat to use alias.

Comment: I don't think i have much else to offer then. Except maybe some sort of prefix to your column names (like reservation_data, booking_data, billing_data) but this will of course impact your entire application.